# 403 forbidden when trying to call a URL using get variable in php

Tags: php, android, url, utf-8, encode

I am trying to make a request from Java (Android) to send a URL to a php file hosted on a web server.
wv.loadUrl(baseurl + "?url=" + URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8"));

where wv is a web view.

The url generated using the above command is:
http://divu.in/TheRedDevil/readhtml/index.php?url=http://www.manutd.com/en/News-And-Features/Football-News/2013/Oct/jimmy-nicholl-knows-jonny-evans-will-battle-for-place.aspx

I also manually tried to open this link using browser and in both cases I got a 403 forbidden error.

Is it a hosting security issue or I am doing something wrong ?
How can this be solved ?

Comment: Make sure that your internet work properly and your url is correct.

Comment: Seems if you cannot open it manually the error is not in PHP but with the server configuration.

Comment: What's the code in index.php in divu.in? How do you capture contents from manutd.com website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested it is not a problem with Android, it is a problem with your PHP code or host.
It seems like your host somehow disallows loading external files.
If you are using file_get_content to load the external content you might try using curl instead - maybe they don't block that.

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init('http://www.example.com'); 
$result = curl_exec($curl); 
echo $result; 
?>
```

Comment: It was the host. I got the confirmation, Thank.. Used POST request in the end to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

That URL returns 403 (FORBIDDEN) even with a standard desktop browser. It's got nothing to do with Android. The problem lies with the server/hosting configuration.

Comment: Yes, that helped me. I kind of wanted to make sure that I am not doing something stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From all the research I did in the past hour, I realised that it is the apaches mod_security settings applied by hostgator.com (the providers).

So, for this particular application, I used post to send data from android app to the server and it worked like a charm.

Anyone working on Android app facing such problem may simple use POST request like:

```
wv.postUrl(baseurl,EncodingUtils.getBytes("url=" + url, "utf-8"));
```